# Autocomplete with categories

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to implement a Jquery Autocomplete with categories and Ajax,

I have the following javascript that I got from [Jquery UI website](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories):

```
  <script>
  $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
          ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
          currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        that._renderItemData( ul, item );
      });
    }
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete.php",
        minLength: 1,

    });             
});
</script>
```

And the file `autocomplete.php`echoes a Json array like this :

```
[
{"label":"Sandy W","category":"Artist"},
{"label":"Shlomi Aber & Itamar Sagi","category":"Artist"},
{"label":"sad","category":"Keyword"}
]
```

However, it seems like jquery doesn't recognise the categories. The values in the array are not separated based on their categories when they show up in the autocomplete's list.

Can it be the quotes in the Json around `label` and `categories` ? I have noticed that in the example provided by jquery `label` and `categories` do not have quotes around them.

Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your looking for categorized search result you need to use `catcomplete` which will display sub-categories whereas `autocomplete` doesn't.

Change this:

```
$(".auto").autocomplete({
```

To:

```
$(".auto").catcomplete({
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EzD8j/)

Comment: How can I have missed that ... THANK YOU !! :)